# Finding a specific sequence of characters in a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code to get the latitude and longitude of a user inputted city.
I've written a code which searches a website and then stores its HTML data in a string.
I now want to search the string(the HTML of the website) for the values.

I've looked into API's, and HTML parsers, but they are all too complicated for me (I'm still in school, just starting out), so please don't recommend those unless its absolutely impossible to do without them.
Code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;
class websearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //gets the city
        out.println("enter city, add plus between multiple words");
        String term = sc.nextLine();

        try {URL url = new URL("http://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=" + term + "&country=");
        URLConnection ucl = url.openConnection();
        InputStream stream = ucl.getInputStream();
        int i;
        //the string in which the html code will be stored
        String code = " ";
        while ((i=stream.read())!= -1) {
            code += Character.toString((char)i);
        }
        //printing the html, only for testing
        System.out.print(code);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
    }
}
```

This code prints a string too large to be pasted here, but the values I want to find look like this:

```
<td nowrap="">N 40° 42' 51''</td>
<td nowrap="">W 74° 0' 21''</td>
```

How could I find this sequence of characters, and then store only the latitude and longitude in a variable?

Comment: Since there will be multiple cities returned it would be important to know which one you want to get. Apart from that, the site you are using offers an api to get the data as easily readable json/xml data instead of html. Usually what you are doing is against the site's TOS

Comment: Searching code for the first and second degree signs (which appears only there), assuming you are willing to take the first matching city, and then going backwards until an NESW and forward to the < sign could work. But probably a regular expression would be good, too.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://julien.gunnm.org/geek/programming/2015/09/13/how-to-get-geocoding-information-in-java-without-google-maps-api/) tutorial should be of some use to you. it goes over how to get the geocode data without actually using the google maps API. If you follow what it says, you should have a fairly easy time implementing it.

The end result is that you will enter the street address of the location you want, and it will return the latitude and longitude in searchable variables.

Primary working class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class OpenStreetMapUtils {

    public final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("OpenStreeMapUtils");

    private static OpenStreetMapUtils instance = null;
    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    public OpenStreetMapUtils() {
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    public static OpenStreetMapUtils getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new OpenStreetMapUtils();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private String getRequest(String url) throws Exception {

        final URL obj = new URL(url);
        final HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        if (con.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            return null;
        }

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        return response.toString();
    }

    public Map<String, Double> getCoordinates(String address) {
        Map<String, Double> res;
        StringBuffer query;
        String[] split = address.split(" ");
        String queryResult = null;

        query = new StringBuffer();
        res = new HashMap<String, Double>();

        query.append("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=");

        if (split.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            query.append(split[i]);
            if (i < (split.length - 1)) {
                query.append("+");
            }
        }
        query.append("&format=json&addressdetails=1");

        log.debug("Query:" + query);

        try {
            queryResult = getRequest(query.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error when trying to get data with the following query " + query);
        }

        if (queryResult == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Object obj = JSONValue.parse(queryResult);
        log.debug("obj=" + obj);

        if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj;
            if (array.size() > 0) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) array.get(0);

                String lon = (String) jsonObject.get("lon");
                String lat = (String) jsonObject.get("lat");
                log.debug("lon=" + lon);
                log.debug("lat=" + lat);
                res.put("lon", Double.parseDouble(lon));
                res.put("lat", Double.parseDouble(lat));

            }
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

How to call the above working class:

```
public class GetCoordinates {

    static String address = "The White House, Washington DC";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Double> coords;
        coords = OpenStreetMapUtils.getInstance().getCoordinates(address);
        System.out.println("latitude :" + coords.get("lat"));
        System.out.println("longitude:" + coords.get("lon"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably paste the inportant parts of the tutorial here just in case the link dies.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart as you requested, I added the critical portions of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

use XPath is a easy way.

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(<uri_as_string>);
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(<xpath_expression>);
```

as for , try something like below:
/xxx/td[@nowrap='']/text()